# Camel XML routes: can I give a "uri" attribute in a <from> element the value of a Java constant?

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

If I have a String Java constant `com.example.Constants.MY_URI`, can I somehow use it to assign the value of a `uri` attribute in a Camel XML file?

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>   
    <from uri="aaa" /> <-- how to use MY_URI here?
    <to uri="bbb"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

In particular, is there a way to use one of the Camel [languages](http://camel.apache.org/languages.html) for this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**
After more work with camel and better know. It is possible to use one of the camel languages to define where message shold go, using [recipient-list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html). But you can't use it as a  replacement of `from` - it must be hardcoded or taken from properties file as I described below.
**end edit**

I don't know if that is possible, but there is another option:

you can use [propertyPlaceholder](http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html):

```
<camelContext ...>
   <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="com/mycompany/myprop.properties"/>
</camelContext>
```

and you need to put your constans into myprop.properties files:

```
example.from.property.name=direct:start
```

then you can use that property inside from:

```
<from uri="{{example.from.property.name}}" />
```